# Texts of a question or answer doesn't show!

Tags: bug, answers, android-app

I click on a question and the the texts of answers don't show. Only comments are visible!

ALL INVISIBLE!

[image]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: GT-S7582

  - OS Version: 6.0.1 (ea11add609)

Comment: On all questions or on a specific one? If a specific one, can you share a link? Does this happen on all sites or a specific site?

Comment: All questions and answers

Comment: I cant view the contente of this post